# Cloned object is changing original object even with using a copy constructor

Tags: java, reference, copy-constructor

I have a `State` object called `state`. I am trying to make a clone of it by calling a function `applyMoveCloning()` which creates a new `State` object called `newState` by using a copy constructor.

```
public State applyMoveCloning(State oldState, Move move) {
    State newState = new State(oldState); // Calls copy constructor
    applyMove(newState, move);            // Calls applyMove() on the newState
    return newState;
}
```

Here is where I call `applyMoveCloning()`

```
State clonedState = game.applyMoveCloning(state, moves.get(i));
```

The problem is, whenever I make changes to `clonedState`, it is changing the properties of my old `state` even though they are different objects (one just has the same properties as the other)

This is my copy constructor

```
public State(State another) {
    this.width = another.width;  
    this.height = another.height; 
    this.board = another.board; 
}
```

How can this be happening? It's not like I'm cloning by using `State newState = state;` so I don't understand.

Comment: What class should I show, there's not really anything else that deals with the copying.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Yes it's a `int[][]`

Comment: Show us `State`. Show us its fields.

Comment: Well there's your answer. Arrays are mutable.

Comment: Hm, so how can I work around this so that they have separate boards?

Comment: Just make a new int[][] and copy values one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which properties are affected?

Assuming `width` and `height` are integers, they are copied by value and not likely to change.

`board`, on the other hand, looks like a reference and your cloned state is sharing it with the old state.

Comment: How could I fix it so that, they both have separate boards then?

Comment: @Brejuro: You're going to have to copy the board int[][] array value by value.